# Swift 3 compiler optimisation causes different result when checking type

Tags: swift, optimization, swift3

I'm experiencing different results when the Swift compiler optimisation is enabled.

This arose from me needing to check if an object passed to a generic function is a class type (so I can store a `weak` ref to it).

With no optimisation, the type reported by `type(of:)` of the value passed to `doSomething` was the correct class (`AppDelegate`). However with optimisations enabled, the type is reported as the generic type (in this case, `Barable`). So my check to see if the object is a class `isClass` differed with various optimisation levels.

Is this a bug or expected behaviour?

```
import UIKit

class Foo<T> {
    func doSomething(value: T) {

        print(type(of: value))
        let isClass = type(of: value) is AnyClass
        print(isClass)

        // Swift Compiler Optimisation: None
        // - type(of: value) == AppDelegate
        // - isClass = true

        // Swift Compiler Optimisation: Single File Optimisation
        // - type(of: value) == Barable
        // - isClass = false

    }
}

protocol Barable { }

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, Barable {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let foos = Foo<Barable>()
        foos.doSomething(value: self)

        return true

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a known bug, see [SR-2867](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2867)